# How to imitate stylized ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I'm trying to create a ListView that is rounded and white-ish:

[image]

So far, I've tried to use < / style> attributes to set the background of the listview, but I can't get this effect. It'd be great if anyone can give me tips.

I know I'll have to use a custom listview, and thus I'm confident I'll have to re-create this in XML for a custom list item.

Answer (score 1):

You can create this by adding following code :

Create **rounded_corners.xml** inside drawable folder like this :

**rounded_corners.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient android:startColor="color of your choice" android:endColor="color of your choice" 
            android:angle="270"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
</shape>
```

and add this on listview like this :

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
       >
    </ListView>
```